# how to give a user permission to a webservice

Tags: c++, web-services, system, asterisk

I have a webservice running on ubuntu server. This webservice has a method :

```
...
main()
{
soap_serve(soap_new());
}
ns_call(std::string who, std::string &result)
{
int j;
j=system ("asterisk -rx \"reload\"");

return SOAP_OK;
}
```

ON THE CLIENT SIDE THE RETURN IS OK BUT THE command line is not executed. WHY? please help. I am stacked

Comment: Are you sure the command is not executed? Maybe the web server just doesn't have permission to do the asterisk reload.

Comment: and how can i give to the webservice the permission to do asterisk reload? need some help. thx!!! i am new to this stuff

Comment: Which user executes the webservice?
You must give it the privileges with "chmod +x" console command.

Comment: i did give chmod+x wbservice. but still no reloading

Comment: @RenanGreinert +x is not the correct permission. Asterisk needs READ and WRITE permission on the control socket in order to connect using -r.

Comment: @AngelDream, how to give a user permission to remotely control Asterisk is a different question. If that's what you want to know, edit your question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am presuming that the command is actually running but it's not able to connect to Asterisk and issue the reload command because the user that is running the web server does not have permission to connect to Asterisk.

Two solutions. The first one is recommended.

## sudo

Configure `sudo` to allow the web server user to execute the specific command "`asterisk -rx reload`" as the `asterisk` user:

```
www-data    (asterisk) NOPASSWD: /usr/sbin/asterisk -rx reload
```

And then use this as the command you pass to `system()`:

```
system("sudo -u asterisk /usr/sbin/asterisk -rx reload");
```

## socket permissions

`asterisk -r` uses a UNIX-domain socket to connect to the Asterisk server. The location of the socket may vary depending on your system but look for something like `/var/run/asterisk.ctl`. By default, the permissions of this socket are probably set so that only the `asterisk` user (or root) can connect.

You need to arrange for the web server user to have permission to read and write to this socket. For example, you could `chmod` the socket to `a+rwx` to make it usable by any user on the system. (Don't do this if you have untrusted users on the system!) Or you could grant grant group write permission to this socket and `chgrp` it to the group that the web server runs as.

No matter how you do it, be aware that you are granting permission for things to execute potentially dangerous actions on behalf of your Asterisk server.

Comment: where do i have to add www-data    (asterisk) NOPASSWD: /usr/sbin/asterisk -rx reload

Comment: 1. `www-data` is what Debian uses by default as the web server user. MAke sure it's correct for you. 2. You need to put that in the sudoers file. Use the `visudo` command to edit it.

Comment: i am sorry i don't understand. i am wokring on ubuntu. could you please be more specific? i am so sorry. so i have to edit in the comand line NOPASSWD:/ usr/sbin/asterisk...? i did put in my webservice system(..); but the application at clients writes that xml response is not the same with what i send.

Comment: @AngelDream, read my comment. It says to use `visudo`. There's plenty of documentation in manpages and Google results if you're not sure how `sudo` works.

Comment: Thx for advices Celada. Really appreciate. I tested the system command and the result is: usage: sudo -h | -K | -k | -L | -V
usage: sudo -v [-AknS] [-p prompt]
usage: sudo -l[l] [-AknS] [-g groupname|#gid] [-p prompt] [-U username] [-u username|#uid] [-g groupname|#gid] [command]
usage: sudo [-AbEHknPS] [-C fd] [-g groupname|#gid] [-p prompt] [-u username|#uid] [-g groupname|#gid] [VAR=value] [-i|-s]
            [<command>]
usage: sudo -e [-AknS] [-C fd] [-g groupname|#gid] [-p prompt]

Comment: Oops, I confused `sudo` syntax with `sh` syntax. `sudo` doesn't take `-c`. Try `system("sudo -u asterisk /usr/sbin/asterisk -rx reload");` instead

Comment: it's still not working. I have error:sudo: unknows user: asterisk

Comment: Then obviously your asterisk server is running under a user account other than `asterisk`. Figure out what account that is and substitute that instead. I'm stopping this here. Stackoverflow comments are not a tech support forum.

Comment: thx. you were right!!. now ihave the error sudo: /usr/sbin/asterisk -rx reload: command not fount. but this is the command line:)..THX A LOT!! REALLY APPRECIATE! I AM NEW TO THIS STUFF.I HAVE TO SOLVE THIS AS SOON AS POSSIBLE